# IntelliJ run configuration environment variables not appearing in System.getenv

Tags: java, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I have an IntelliJ project. I have an `Application` class with a `main` function and a chunk of AWS code, part of which looks for the AWS credentials in the environment.

Following these instructions, I set those credentials as environment variables in the run configuration:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html
[image]

Previously, I tried using the EnvFile plugin (which is still active), and pointed it at an appropriate env file, also containing the AWS credentials (as well as other env vars).

I am using this code snippet to print out all the environment variables:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
for (String key : env.keySet()) {
  sb.append(key + ": " + env.get(key)  + "\n");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

I then run that configuration from the Run menu.

My global environment variables are printed (as expected) but none from the configuration, or from the EnvFile.

Where should I look next to resolve this issue?

Comment: I got a successful print of my variable with your code. I don't see how you could configure it to behave differently. Did you invalidate caches and restart? (Not that I expect it to help in this case, but it's has solved more than one mystery for me over the years)

Comment: How do I invalidate caches? Also, I tried this same code and instructions in a fresh, empty project and as expected it worked just fine. There's something else going on in this project (which is a modified duplicate of another project), but I don't have any clear way to investigate.

Comment: In menu `File` there is a `Invalidate caches/restart` option.

Comment: @Narfanator Did it help?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with intelliJ 2021 and 2022 on an M1 macbook. I forced to dump all my environment variables in my application properties to be able to run my application locally. Has anyone faced/solved this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue today on my M1 Macbook with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 (Ultimate Edition).

The fix for me, in this instance, was to upgrade the Gradle wrapper version in the project. Specifically, from `6.2.1` to `7.5.1`.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Community Edition). Upgrading Gradle wrapper to 6.9.4 fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I'm using a mac m1. This is a workaround. Remove the cache and preferences for intellij on ~/Library path.  Delete all the files in the below path.

```
~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains
~/Library/Caches/JetBrains
~/Library/Preferences/JetBrains
~/Library/Logs/JetBrains
~/Library/Saved Application
State/com.jetbrains.intellij.savedState
~/Library/Preferences/jetbrains.idea.d7ab3053
~/Library/Preferences/com.jetbrains.intellij
```

You may lose you ide settings, but couldn't help.